# What is the difference between git config --list and cat .gitconfig?

Tags: git

What is the difference between them both? I'm learning in my tutorial that they give out the global configuration settings, but I'm not really sure what the difference between them is, and when I should use either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git config --list` will list all configurations currently visible (in the current directory)

It will list **all** the configurations, **system** wide at the top, followed by the **global** configuration (most often found under `~/.gitconfig`), followed by the **local** configurations (if inside a git repository).

---

`cat .gitconfig` will most likely only work in your home directory (`~/`)

Additionally the format of the two will differ.

See the documentation of [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more details.

---

I don't see a reason why **not** to use `git config --list` always.

Answer (score 6):

`cat .gitconfig` shows you the content of the file .gitconfig. If this is the one that is used by git (this is configurable), then it is identical to the according level of settings.

In Git you have three levels of settings files, in repository, global for your user and global for the whole computer with all its users. `git config --list` will list all of them that are in effect in the place where you are.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitconfig` is one of four configuration files that `git config --list` will search for configuration options. `.gitconfig` contains only the user-specific configurations (also called global configuration), but you can also have system-specific and repository-specific configurations. To get a full view of the configuration in your current directory, you should use `git config --list`. Check out the `FILES` section of `git config --help`.

Answer (score 0):

You can list your gitconfig with `cat .git/config` from any directory.